# Singleton on multiple JVMs using JNDI

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, jndi

It is said that Singleton is always on per JVM basis, but somebody asked me to create a singleton instance throughout multiple JVMs. I have found a solution to create an object on one JVM, register it with the JNDI, and lookup that object on different JVMs.

Please share your insight on this.

Comment: What's the question? "share your insight on this" is too broad.

Comment: @Cam Every JVM instance will have a different process running on it. I have a doubt on this since you will be requiring inter process communication to communicate between the JVMs and update them with the information that who is holding the object, anyways how will you shift an object from JVM instance a to another I have a big doubt Even I would like help from people and would appreciate if somebody can put more light on this :)

Comment: @SanyamGoel Thanks for your help. But I think JNDI works in this way

Comment: @Pablo I apologize if my question is not clear, just wanted to ask if we can have singleton throughout multiple JVM using JNDI

Answer (score 2):

My insight is that it won't work.

Even if you lookup the singleton using JNDI and then use it, the singleton will effectively be created on the JVM you are using as well.

Only way is to just invoke methods on that singleton bean remotely. May be via something like RMI.

Comment: **the singleton will effectively be created on the JVM you are using as well.** Would you please elaborate this line ?? which JVM you are talking about here, Is this the same JVM on which the singleton is created and registered with the JNDI

Comment: No the one you are calling it from. It should be easy enough for you to test though...