# Can I use Jetty as a JNDI server?

Tags: jetty, jndi

It is possible to store objects in JNDI using Jetty as explained in the [reference documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi.html). These objects can be looked up by webapps running in the Jetty instance.

Is it possible to look up these objects from an app running in *another* JVM ? If so, what would be the provider class and the directory url ?

Comment: According to the following answer (seems like the same problem), it may not work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16525910/1850609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the scoping of JNDI is really only up to the JVM level.  If you want to access objects on another jvm then you would need to sort that coordination out another way of which there are tons of different approaches, expose something via rest, use a clustered caching solution, coordinate through a database, use zookeeper, etc etc etc.  All depends on *what* you are trying to get access to, which may be a nice StackOverflow question if it hasn't already been asked and answered.